# mySql WHERE `xml<date>` = '11/21/2010'

Tags: sql, mysql, xml

i have a mySql database, and it has an field for each entry called xml, which contains XML.
i would like to know if there is syntax to select xml values like normal fields.

for example if i wanted to select all entries with the date of 11/21/2010
i try something like this, but the syntax is wrong, since i don't know how to work with xml well in mySql.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `table` 
 WHERE `xml<date>` = '11/21/2010'
```

Ideally, I would like to compare it to another field:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `table` 
 WHERE `xml<date>` != `date`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ExtractValue](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) function with an XPath expression to get your desired field:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE ExtractValue(xml,'/a/suitable/xpath/expression') != `date`
```